# Intervention problem in composition relationship class

Tags: c#, oop, composition

I have two classes and they have composition relationship between them showed in code.

In composition If I destroy the upper building object flat instances inside it will be gone with it. Due to the fact that flats dependent to the building. But f1 object's presence is independent of b1. b1 is just holding f1's reference. If I destroy b1 f1 will still exist.

Here is my question:
By doing that(Adding a new flat object to the building in main) did I broke the composition relationship ? Or what happened in there in aspects of oop? I think this is inappropriate but actually I have no idea. I'm a newbie.

Thanks in advance.

```
    internal class Flat
    {
        private int doorNumber;

        public Flat(int doorNumber)
        {
            this.doorNumber = doorNumber;
        }
    }
```

```
        private List<Flat> flats;

        internal List<Flat> Flats { get => flats; set => flats = value; }

        public Building()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Flats.Add(new Flat(101+i));
            }
        }
```

Then I'm doing this in main func:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Building b1 = new Building();
            Flat f1 = new Flat(12);
            b1.Flats.Add(f1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you do not wish the Flat object to live without being attached to building object then you should make sure that the Flat object can not be initialized independently. Moreover you have `Flats` property of building class is accessible outside. This will allow the external code to modify it.

Comment: What you are doing is exactly how most 1:many relationships work in .NET. Think about, for instance, the `Form.Controls`, `DataSet.Tables`, `ComboBox.Items`, etc, etc. These are all collection properties where you create the object first and add it to the collection. You would only do it differently if you have a specific reason to.

Comment: The thing you're doing wrong is making your `Flats` property read/write. By doing so, you allow external code to replace the collection itself with a completely different one. The property should be read-only, so external code can get the existing collection and modify its contents, but not replace it entirely. Again, that's how the vast majority of collection properties work, including the examples I mentioned earlier.